# Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 not installing on asus tuf a17

Tags: installation, operating-system, windows-10, ubuntu-20.04, bios

I have recently bought a laptop (asus tuf a17 gaming) In which I want to install Ubuntu with the help of bootable pendrive But when i select that pendrive in boot menu nothing is happening
I have have also tried it by disabling secure boot and fast boot
But nothing is happening.
I am using winsetupfromusb to make the pendrive bootable.
Also the ubuntu iso installation works fine on vmware.

Comment: Did you follow the steps given here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNoe9vz2V5E

Comment: Yeah but there is no csm mode in my bios menu

Comment: No there is no such option in bios

Comment: Ok, because Google is ..... a final attempt: see: https://forum.zorin.com/t/how-to-boot-from-usb-on-asus-tuf-a17/2897

Comment: It was a problem with winsetupfromusb. Now with rufus i am able to boot ubuntu. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use https://www.balena.io/etcher/
but also you boot order it's correct? do you have some error?

Comment: I have selected pendrive as first booting device. But on restart windows 10 boots up